# Necesito hacer una query para seleccionar un dato sin repetirlo MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

Recurro a ustedes con la siguiente consulta:

Tengo 2 tablas ("cursos" y "jornadas_curso"), donde hago la siguiente query:

```
    SELECT 
        cursos.nombre_curso, 
        cursos.id_curso, 
        DATE_FORMAT( jornadas_curso.fechas_curso,'%d/%m/%y' )
          AS Fechas_Cursos, 
        jornadas_curso.horario_curso, 
        jornadas_curso.tipo_jornada, 
        cursos.id_relator, 
        cursos.descripcion, 
        cursos.vacantes,
        cursos.ubicacion 
        from cursos inner join jornadas_curso
      on jornadas_curso.id_curso=cursos.id_curso
        and disponible='si' and vacantes >0
      AND fechas_curso > NOW()
    order by fechas_curso DESC;
```

Con esto selecciono el curso, su id, fecha, jornada, id del relator, su descripcion, las vacantes y la ubicación del curso. Como un curso puede tener mas de 1 fecha, hice la tabla cursos para guardar sus datos, excepto la fecha, jornada y horario, ya que esos los guardo en jornada_curso (junto con su respectivo id del curso), y debido a esto, al hacer la consulta se me repiten las filas con el mismo nombre del curso, ya que basicamente, son el mismo curso pero con diferente fecha:

[image: Foto de la consulta en phpmyadmin]

Como puedo hacer para que, en la consulta, no se me repita el nombre del curso? (Tambien probe con select DISTINCT, tb con el mismo resultado)

Comment: lo que puedes hacer para esto es concatenar las fechas del mismo curso en un solo campo, ya que tu unico dato diferente es la fecha

Comment: Fernankin, y como podría hacer eso? (Llevo poco en mysql)

Comment: Para que nesecitas esa consulta... piensalo, a donde la vas a utilizar. Veras como dice @Fernankin el distinct no te funcionan por las fechas. Ahora, necesitas esas fechas?, si no la necesitas quitala del select y aplica el distinct. Pero si necesitas las fechas y la agrupas en un solo campo, luego donde consumas ese query vas a tener que aplicar algun tipo de split para poder separarlas al menos que no les interese mostrar todo un chorizo de fecha en un solo campo.

Comment: ¿Y que es lo que buscas ver en la consulta? te pregunto, por que te estan orientando hacia la concatenación, cuando tal vez sea un problema de agrupación.

Answer (score 0):

Para seleccionar sin repetir debes usar DISTINCT así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cursos.nombre_curso .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas no es un `DISTINCT` sino un `GROUP BY`.

Verás el `DISTINCT` que has probado hace lo que tiene que hacer, aunque no lo que tú esperas que haga: ese curso que para ti está repetido, al tener fechas diferentes, no es un registro repetido, lo único que está repetido es uno de los campos.

Con el `GROUP BY nombre_curso` eso ya no te volverá a pasar, pero tendrás que aplicar una función de totales (`MAX`, `MIN`, `AVG`, `SUM`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, ...) en cada campo que pudiera tomar valores diferentes, de lo contrario, te mostrará el primero que se encuentre.

Inténtalo y, si tienes alguna dificultad, amplío la respuesta.

```
SELECT 
    cursos.nombre_curso, 
    cursos.id_curso,
    GROUP_CONCAT( 
      DATE_FORMAT( jornadas_curso.fechas_curso,'%d/%m/%y' )
        AS Fechas_Cursos, 
      jornadas_curso.horario_curso, 
      jornadas_curso.tipo_jornada, 
      cursos.id_relator, 
      cursos.descripcion, 
      cursos.vacantes,
      cursos.ubicacion 
    )
    FROM cursos JOIN jornadas_curso
      ON jornadas_curso.id_curso=cursos.id_curso
      AND disponible='si' AND vacantes >0
  AND fechas_curso > NOW()
  GROUP BY cursos.nombre_curso
  ORDER BY fechas_curso DESC;
```

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

podria aplicar algo como lo siguiente

creas un nuevo select dentro del select principal, para obtener las fechas del curso, deberas construir tus relaciones en el select y luego concatenas todos los resultados. Te quedaria algo mas o menos asi
SELECT distinct
            cursos.nombre_curso, 
            cursos.id_curso,

```
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fechas_curso),
    --DATE_FORMAT( jornadas_curso.fechas_curso,  '%d/%m/%y' ) AS Fechas_Cursos ,
        --(select fechas_curso from jornadas_curso
        --where cursos.id_curso = jornadas_curso.id_curso
        --for XML PATH ('') ) fecha_curso,

        jornadas_curso.horario_curso, 
        jornadas_curso.tipo_jornada, 
        cursos.id_relator, 
        cursos.descripcion, 
        cursos.vacantes,
        cursos.ubicacion 
        from cursos
        inner join jornadas_curso on jornadas_curso.id_curso =cursos.id_curso
        and disponible='si' and vacantes >0 AND fechas_curso > NOW( ) 
        order by fechas_curso DESC
```

Comment: Fernankin y para que es el   for XML PATH ('') ?

Comment: para concatenar, en este caso aplico ' ' para dar un espacio entre los resultados que encuentre

Comment: Es que corri tu query en el phpmyadmin de localhost pero me aparece el siguiente error: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'XML PATH ('') ) fecha_curso, jornadas_curso.horario_curso, jor' en la linea 8

Comment: Lo unico que fallo fue el for XML PATH ('') ) fechas_curso, donde estaba como fecha_curso (le falto una s), pero sigue con el mismo problema

Comment: intenta quitando el select y aplica 'GROUP_CONCAT'

Comment: he actualizado mi respuesta para que verifiques

Comment: Hola Fernankin, recien estoy retomando el codigo, lo pruebo y te comento, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Lo probe y aun aparece el error, pero no tengo como agregar fotos en los comentarios:

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fechas_curso), --DATE_FORMAT( jornadas_curso.fechas_c' en la linea 1

Comment: Quita todas las lineas que estan comentadas, solo deja las que son necesarias